# Linq to Entities: Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Using Linq to Entities I need to filter an my entity set based on a list of complex objects that represent criteria.  For example:

```
var criteria = new[]
{
new { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Smith" },
new { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe" }
};
```

I am try to do the following:

```
var filtered = PersonEntities.where(person => criteria.Any(c => c.FirstName == person.FirstName && c.LastName == person.LastName)).ToList();
```

This results in an error due to the query builder not being able to process the complex object.  I know that if I had an Id value to filter on, I could simply select it into an in-memory list and replace the complex object with it in the linq query criteria.  However I have not been able to find a solution when multiple fields are required in the criteria.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think your best bet is to create a helper method that will generate proper Expression Tree, which would be based on `AND`/`OR`s

Comment: Maybe you could create a list of strings where each one is the first and last name concatenated together with a delimiter between them that you know will not be a character in either.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment, in this specific case we can work around the problem easily without having to build a complex Expression tree manually. If your `criteria` should be what you declared, you can always re-shape it to a list of strings containing firstname and lastname separated by a underscore (this should not be any of the valid characters for name). Then you have just primitive collection/array and can totally use it in the linq query, something like this:

```
var first_last = criteria.Select(e=> string.Format("{0}_{1}",e.FirstName,e.LastName));
var filtered = PersonEntities.Where(person => first_last.Any(e=>e == person.FirstName + "_" + person.LastName)).ToList();
```

If building the Expression tree, I guess you have to even touch the so-called `ExpressionVisitor`, it's quite a long code (at least 7-8 times of what we've done here).